# What is difference between Canon EF-S 18-55 mm IS and EF-S 18-55 mm IS II lenses?

Tags: lens, canon, kit-lens

What are physical differences between both to spot on the sight?

Other than that, what are technical differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this article in Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EF-S_18%E2%80%9355mm_lens#EF-S_18.E2.80.9355mm_IS_I.2FII

that refers to this other page from Ken Rockwell:

http://www.kenrockwell.com/canon/lenses/18-55mm-is-ii.htm

the only technical difference is a different IS algorithm that recognizes panning.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there is no difference - optically, they are exactly the same.

Given the above, it doesn't matter to much, but original has a silver band round it and the II version doesn't.

As an aside, exactly the same applies to the 55-250 as well.